# Different GUI for landscape orientation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make another GUI for my landscape orientation? How should I do it?

Can I make two canvas: one for portrait mode and another one for landscape?

Please give me advice! :)

Comment: My advice is to read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: @Plutonix thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the Input.deviceOrientation to get the orientation of the device. Than you can check if the deviceorientation is Portrait or LandscapeLeft or LandscapeRight

See the documentation
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/DeviceOrientation.html

If the orientation is changed you can disable the first canvas and enable the second canvas! You can run this check in the Update() function!

I Hope this information helps!